# How import the lineage of airflow to the atlas?

Tags: airflow, apache-atlas

I do like this: 
https://airflow.apache.org/lineage.html#

in my airflow.cfg:

```
[lineage]
   backend = airflow.lineage.backend.atlas

[atlas]
  username = my_username
  password = my_password
  host = host
  port = 21000
```

I  run the sample DAG in ariflow, then I meet err as follows:

> {**init**.py:44} DEBUG - Cannot import airflow.lineage.backend.atlas due to Module "airflow.lineage.backend" does not define a "atlas" attribute/class

could someone give me a help?

Answer (score 1):

I just updated this part.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/lineage.rst#apache-atlas

You can try

```
backend = airflow.lineage.backend.atlas.AtlasBackend
```

Any feedback is welcomed :)

Comment: this page is removed and moved to https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/apache-airflow/lineage.rst